# How can I resolve java.lang.module.FindException when running JavaFX on Eclipse for Mac?

Tags: eclipse, javafx

Hi everyone I am a newbie and in school one of my assignments required that I install the JavaFX plug-in. I am at a complete loss with this program. I have followed several tutorials to download and install FX over and over again and I still get the same error message when I go to run it:

An error occurred during initialization of the boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Where am I going wrong and how do I resolve this issue?

I have gone step by step through several tutorials. I have also gone to the extreme measure of uninstalling Eclipse, and starting from scratch I do not know what it is that I am missing.

Comment: Sounds like you have a module-info.java in your project so you are using the Java module system. You will need to update the module-info.java to require the javafx.controls module. Alternatively delete the module-info.java to stop using the module system.

Comment: See also [_Getting Started with JavaFX:JavaFX and Eclipse_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), which addresses the [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) plugin.